# Migrate Google API credentials

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-platform

Is there any way to migrate Google API credentials from one account/project to another? I created OAuth credentials a while ago on one of my accounts, but now I'd like to move it to a different account. I don't want to recreate the credentials since that invalidate already authorized users in production.

Comment: Seems like there is no such thing